# Why won't Cyberduck connect via SFTP?

Tags: ubuntu, sftp

I'm receiving the following error when trying to connect via Cyberduck SFTP to an Ubuntu 9.10 server that I am able to successfully ssh into:

```
[main] ERROR ch.cyberduck.core.sftp.SFTPSession - Connection attempt canceled
```

I have other Ubuntu servers that I am able to successfully SSH into and Cyberduck is able to SFTP into. I've reviewed `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and am now at a loss as to what else to check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your .bashrc or shell login is producing output sftp or scp will fail: [FAQ](http://www.openssh.org/faq.html#2.9).  Try issuing a remote command via ssh:

`ssh cookiemonster@myserver.com /bin/true`

If the above spits out any text, you need to fix the offending text generator in the cookiemonster account's login scripts.  No fortune cookies upon login for sftp. ;(

Comment: I should have asked this question much earlier and saved myself quite a bit of time. I modified `.bashrc` to eliminate any text spit out and Cyberduck works beautifully. Many Thanks.